# HowTo sort std::map by first and second params?

Tags: sorting, dictionary

Here is my `std::map` example, like `std::map< string, string > my_map;`

```
//   ABC | aaa      ABC | aaa
//   DEF | def      ABC | dcd
//   BCD | def  ->  ABC | zzz
//   DEF | bcd      BCD | def
//   ABC | dcd      DEF | bcd
//   ABC | zzz      DEF | def
```

As you can see, I'm trying to sort left `std::map` and get the right one.

And here is my code (I used not strings, but my custom types. any way, in final, I'm sorting strings):

```
template < typename T1, typename T2 >
struct less_second
{
     typedef std::pair< T1, T2 > type;
     bool operator ()( type const& _left, type const& _right ) const
     {
          return ( (*_left.first).name() < (*_right.first).name() ) &&
                 ( (*_left.second).name() < (*_right.second).name() );
     }
};
```

**Problem**: when I use only in `less_second`

```
return (*_left.first).name() < (*_right.first).name();
```

All data from the *first* column sorted, but *second* column not (of course, because we are used only *first*!)

The mirrored situation, when I use only

```
return (*_left.second).name() < (*_right.second).name();
```

The *second* column sorted.

**BUT** I need to sort and first and the second columns at once. How to code this? What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for help!

---

Sorry, forget this code:

```
std::vector< std::pair< CompanyPtr, ContractorPtr > > n_map_( buddies_ccm_.begin(), buddies_ccm_.end() );
std::sort( n_map_.begin(), n_map_.end(), less_second< CompanyPtr, ContractorPtr >() );
```

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, add the "homework" tag.

Comment: @jeremytrimble No, it's not! For home work I show you not the question only, but the whole problem (with code, ideas and etc).

Comment: Regarding your edit: Are you trying to sort a `std::map` or a `std::vector`?

Comment: @Stephan We can't sort `std::map` simple, right? Because, key already sorted with standard less functor. So here I'm trying to use `std::vector` to sort the map with my predefined functor `less_second`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison function is wrong. It does not work when both `first.name()` are equal. Try something like this:

```
 bool operator ()( type const& _left, type const& _right ) const
 {
     if ((*_left.first).name() > (*_right.first).name())
        return false;
     if ((*_left.first).name() < (*_right.first).name())
        return true;
     return ( (*_left.second).name() < (*_right.second).name() );
 }
```

Comment: Yes!!! That is correct answer, `std::vector` now sorted like I want! Great thanks, Stephan.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little bit confused by the term "columns". Are you talking about keys and values?

A std::map is always ordered by key. You can specify a compare object at construction time of your map to define that order. But this compare object does not compare `std::pair`s, but objects of the key type of your map.

Moreover, a key in a map is unique. Thus, there cannot be two entries with the key "ABC" in the map.

I suppose you try to sort the map with `std::sort` from `<algorithm>`. I'm not sure what happens in this case, but I think it is not what you expect to happen.

Comment: "Are you talking about keys and values?" Yes, of course, it's key/value.

Comment: In `std::map` not only strings, but it's my custom data types. I think when I'm trying to compare like this: `( (*_left.first).name() < (*_right.first).name() ) && ( (*_left.second).name() < (*_right.second).name() )` compare method became "unstable", because when first "column"-key sorted, all that data table changed, but then I'm trying to sort the second "column"-value, and it's incorrect...

Answer (score 0):

You only want to take the second column into account if `_left->first` and `_right->first` are equal.  Put another way, you want to make your code compare the `first` fields first, and fall back to comparing the `second` fields only if the `first` comparison is inconclusive (which happens when both `first`s are equal).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve what you want with a `std::map` as it has been already explained in another answer. If your pairs don't have repetitions you could use a set of pairs:

```
std::set<std::pair<std::string, std::string> > pair_set;
```

You don't need to provide a comparator as `std::pair` already supports the kind of comparison you require.

Comment: No, I have to write my own comparator functor, because it's not a simple strings, but my own custom data types (with strings, ints, and other data)...